# Как из строки сделать ссылку на переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я знаю, что пример плохой, но ничего лучше я придумать не смог. Нужно из переменной LinkPointString
как-то сделать ссылку на переменную point1. И да, просто print(point1) не подойдёт :)

```
point1 = 0
IndexPoint = 1
LinkPointString = 'point'+str(IndexPoint)
print(B)
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "ссылка"?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 возможность изменить или прочитать значение этой переменной

Answer (score 3):

Ну можно через словарь глобальных переменных `globals()` содержание переменной по имени посмотреть:

```
point1 = 3.1415
NamePoint = 'point'
IndexPoint = 1
LinkPointString = NamePoint + str(IndexPoint)
print(globals()[LinkPointString])
```

Вывод:

```
3.1415
```

Comment: А если это не переменная, а ссылка на экземпляр класса?

Comment: @RaKKeta Совершенно без разницы. В питоне все переменные совершенно одинаковые в каких-то смыслах. `x = globals()[LinkPointString]` даёт переменную, а дальше вы делаете с ней то же, что делали бы с той штукой, на которую она указывает. Хотите - экземпляр класса создаёте `x()`, хотите функцию вызываете `x()`, питону без разницы.

Answer (score 0):

из строки сделать ссылку (объявить переменную) можно например так:

```
value = 3.1415
name = 'point1'

globals()[name] = value
```

теперь `point1` ссылается на `3.1415`

```
print(f'{point1 = }')  # point1 = 3.1415
```